# React how can i replace the valeur of data

Tags: reactjs, fetch

as you can see on [image], i have two way to get the data.

The first one is localy, use the getdata() to read from local file.

```
  function getData() {
  const data = testData.map(item => {
    return {
      ...item
    };
  });
  return data;
}
```

The second one is a distance.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://XXXXX')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({ todos: data })
      console.log(this.state.todos)
    })  
  }
```

both work, but somehow i can not bind the second one to my app.

i am newbie on react technologie.

Comment: There are two state objects in the code, move `todos` array to the state you create in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't define 2 state obj.
you have to delete one of them